# Infographic for job titles

Tags: information-graphics

Anyone able to share any ideas/inspiration for creating an infographic with job titles? Something to be used on a website which is 1200px wide and 680px high.

[image]

The purpose of the infographic is to present the job titles such as head of Insight, Innovation and Policy, Key Account Manager, BT Global Services etc. This is an example. So to highlight these roles in the graphic on a website.

I have merely created 3 boxes overlapping one another and it's a little dull and needs bringing to life or a total design re-haul. Any ideas? Hope more specific now.

(It's not an org chart just a list of roughly 21 job titles that need to be presented in a more appealing way visually) See attached what I have done- not visually appealing enough. Help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Unfortunately your question is very broad. Can you please explain what you mean by "an inforgraphic with job titles", perhaps post an image showing an example of what kind of infographic you are looking for, or showing what you have tried or what has failed, etc. Perhaps also mention what you want such an infographic to communicate, or explain why an infographic would be better than perhaps a simple list of job title for example. We'd really appreciate it if you could edit your question to supply more information. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question. Hope makes more sense now?

Comment: I think it's a bit broad to merely a "Ask for examples". There are at least a billion ways to make 21 lines of text "interesting". You could merely google search for some infographic examples.

Comment: I have googled ideas. It's just something that has not been done before so I am struggling to come up with ideas and vague input from others for direction. No worries if not able to help - just thought give it a go to ask for any visual references that would help.

Comment: I understand, unfortunately this site isn't really geared toward general ideation. That's a bit too subjective and is really kind of asking for "free work" to some degree.

Comment: I see. Thought it was more about supporting designers and helping each other. No worries.

Comment: Well, we are here to help each other. But StackExchange sites, like this one, may be unlike sites you are accustomed to. Stack sites adhere to a Question <> Answer format. Direct questions with direct answers, not open discussions. Stack sites aren't "Forums". A tad more subjective questions are allowed here compared to other stack sites, merely due to the overall nature of design. But idea farming is merely too broad and ultimately is so specific as to only be helpful to the 1 user posting a question and not very helpful to future users.

Answer (score 5):

You **are** using too **many** bold let**ters** and instead of **making** thi**ngs** clear, they **mess** it up more.

This answer is formatted as an example itself.

### What is the most important information?

The initial recommendation is simply to use hierarchy.

This need to be with a larger size font. Normally we call it a title or heading. You need to have just one per card.

### Group it!

As far as I can see you have no title, but a:

- List of terms
- List of positions
- Or responsibilities
- Or something like that... it is not clear at all.

### Can you use bold?

Of course, but you need to give a clear glimpse of what the bold means. On a large paragraph should be used **only** a few times.

But you are trying to use it to sort of making some organization out of it... so I would use only to differentiate term vs. definition.

**Job description:** Head of formatting department.

**Main goal:** Keeping the card clean enough to be read.

### Where to get some inspiration?

[Just search for Card Design.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=card%20design&t=ffab&atb=v147-3__&iax=images&ia=images) Adapt those ideas as background, **but mainly put your info together and tidy it**.

---

### But...

These ideas are only for the card itself. For the overall "infographic" (which I would not call it as such yet) I would think of it as some kind of organization chart.

Some random cards are not good to explain anything... except if they are posted on a job-seeking page in a newspaper... (Which if the case they would need to be independent of each other)

The organization itself must mean something.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to provide you with an actual solution/idea, but instead talk about ways to get inspiration, which seems to be the main problem here. All graphic designers experience something akin to "writer's block" from time to time, so I can appreciate how infuriating it can be when you get stuck.

One of the first places I go to for inspiration is google images. Obviously, it's great for finding images and ideas. Other places to look are stock image/graphic sites. Amongst these, the [Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com/) can be very useful for finding icons or even just basic ideas for graphical representations.  Sometimes you will see something that hits you immediately, other times it might take a bit longer, but eventually you may find an idea that might fit your requirements (without just copying obviously).  Sometimes you get more than one idea, and you have to try a couple out before discarding the ones that won't work.

As, for your particular problem, have you perhaps thought of a way to jazz up those three rectangles?  I assume these job titles belong to a company/business/organisation.  So, you could try googling these terms looking for clip art with reference to "business/company/organisation". I'm not talking about using a piece of clip art or icon here, but perhaps using a recognizable shape that people might associate with "business/company/organisation" to replace those boring rectangle shapes.

Obviously, you don't want something that is clichéd or overdone. Keep it subtle or abstract - the merest hint of a business connection might suffice.

Hope that helps.